# How to disable "save password to Google?" prompt?

Tags: password, 8.1-oreo

I am currently using a Galaxy Tab A 2016 on Oreo and the above prompt pops up everytime I log in an app. Is there a way to disable this prompt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

FYI, for future readers, I believe the correct way to disable this feature is by going to:

Settings > General management > Language and input

Then, under "Input Assistance," set "Autofill services" to "None."

Comment: This is the correct answer post 2019. However, the path to "autofill services" can vary. If a person cannot find the service, try using the searchbar in settings to find "autofill services".

Comment: This answer addresses keyboard autofill features, but does not answer the question regarding the prompt as described. YZN3RF's answer is correct. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/233168/158516

Answer (score 8):

For me on a Moto G9 with Android 10, the following worked:

- "Settings" > "Accounts"
- Tab the main account for the phone
- "Google Account (Info, security & personalization)"
- "Security" Tab > Scroll all the way down > "Signing in with Google" > "Password Manager"
- Tab the cogwheel in the top right > Disable "Offer to save passwords"
- Voilà

In my special case I had some extra steps, because I was not able to access the "Password Manager" because I apparently used it at some point and would have needed my "Google Sync Passphrase" to get to the password manager.
Therefore I first had to head over to https://chrome.google.com/sync in Chrome, login with  my Google account, scroll all the way down and hit "CLEAR DATA" (which does reset all sync data, including bookmarks etc.).

Edit:
Discovered another setting! Right above "Password Manager" there is "Signing in with Google" which has a "Google Account sign-in prompts" setting ("Allow Google to offer a faster way to sign in with your Google Account on supported third-party sites").

Answer (score 2):

On Android 11 devices method to disable saving user/password autofill prompts:

System settings -> General Management > Autofill service -> None

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after some exploration. Giving a gist,

> You need to modify the Google Account Settings and modify the "Offer to save passwords" options.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security
2. Sign in with your Google Account.
3. Go down the page and you will see a "**Password Manager**" option. Click it.
4. The "Password Manager" is opened. Tap on the **Settings icon** ( a gear icon on the top right ).
5. The **Password Options** page will open. The first option you see is "**Offer to save passwords**".
6. Uncheck the option and its all done!

Comment: I tried the above and it is already off.

Comment: Then the dialog must have been disabled by default. No other setting is provided by Google to perform this action.

Comment: These instructions don't work. As @iLW, in my case the setting is already off for the Google account that I use with Android.